# SlickGrid: How to implement editorLock for concurrent data edits?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slickgrid

I have an editable SlickGrid implemented in a page. Is there a way to implement an editor lock on this grid so I can enable concurrent data edits?

I know the grid has an option called `editorLock` (which is set to `Slick.GlobalEditorLock` by default) - but I am not sure how this gets implemented.

Any pointers on how I implement this through SlickGrid? I want to enable only one user to edit the cell at a time.

**EDIT**: editorLock is local to grid instances and doesn't actually work for different grid instances on different browser sessions. So the only way to achieve this is to have a manual mechanism to keep track of active edits.

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking at this too.  From what I can see it is not a way to manage two different people on two different computers both attempting to edit the same database record at the same time.  Instead it is a way for a single person who has opened a page which multiple grids on it, which are different views on the same table, from attempting to edit the data in one grid and then edit the same data in aother grid before the first one has been saved.